# javascript get filename from string

Tags: javascript

I want to get the first part of a filename from the full filename, for example, from:

```
bee_gees_-_stayin_alive.mp3
```

I want to return: **bee_gees_-_stayin_alive**

How can I do it?

```
var filename = file.name;
var name = filename.split('.');
var lastarray = name.length;
var names = filename.split('.')[lastarray];
```

Comment: With code. [Where is yours?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: great link, totally saving it for future reference.

Comment: I dont have any ideas

Comment: Well, best of luck then, but I'm voting to close as 'too broad,' given you don't appear willing to make an attempt or undertake research to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the index of the last period in the string and get the part of the string before that.

Example:

```
var fullName = "bee_gees_-_stayin_alive.mp3";

var name = fullName.substr(0, fullName.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sfB2v/

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the very basic form of regular expressions since this question could easily be solved by googling a bit, but here I go:

**the dumb way**

```
var filename = "bee_gees_-_stayin_alive.mp3"
var name = filename.split('.')[0]
```

**the proper way**

```
var filename = "bee_gees_-_stayin_alive.mp3"
var name = filename.match(/[a-zA-Z_-]*/)[0]
```

Comment: When string is: **metodik göstəriş buraxılış son1.docx** it returns **metodik**

Comment: that is because the regexp doesn't match? can't you simply get there from the example, jesus. add a space in the regular expression!

Comment: var name = filename.match(/[^.]*/)[0] for the unicode

Comment: I tried this code: `var name = filename.split('.');
var lastarray = name.length;
var names = filename.split('.')[lastarray];` but not worked. Wich part I muse add space?

Comment: you clearly don't understand ANY of the code, so we're just wasting everyone's time here. try to learn programming first.